# breqn package incompatibility

Tags: incompatibility, breqn

Edit: For clarity about what this post is asking, I have placed the specific questions at the beginning of the post.

I would like to understand the technical details of the incompatibilities of `breqn.sty` (v0.98a) with other packages in TexLive2009. These incompatibilities appear to vanish in subsequent editions of TexLive, and I would like to know what changes have been made to the remediate the incompatibilities? Lastly, what does the obscure and unhelpful error message cited below signify?

---

Background to contextualize the above questions:

On an amd64 linux system running TexLive 2009, I find that the package [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) (v0.98a) must be the last package loaded, otherwise it interferes with loading of certain other packages, in particular [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) (v1.4), [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) (v2.11), and [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (v1.0f).

Below, I include an example document that generates an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Null.
\end{document}
```

The output (including the error message) produced upon compilation of this document with [`pdflatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex) is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./breqn.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/breqn.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/flexisym.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/cmbase.sym)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/mathstyle.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.44 \lst@InputCatcodes

?
```

When I compile the same code on a mac osx 10.6 system running MacTeX-2011, the code compiles without error, regardless of when `breqn.sty` is loaded.

The following excerpt from the [`breqn` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf) (Section 6.1) does specify that such incompatibilities may occur:

> As it pushes the envelope of what is possible within the context of LaTeX 2ε, the `breqn` package will tend to break other packages when used in combination with them, or to fail itself, when there are any areas of internal overlap; successful use may in some cases depend on package loading order.

Comment: You should upgrade your TeX distribution. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu which will tell you how to install the newest TeX Live on Linux.

Comment: Thank you. I was more interested in some of the technical details of why the package was causing issues in one distribution and not another.

Comment: If you want an analysis, you should show a minimal example to test on.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I have added a MWE that reproduces the error on TexLive 2009.

Comment: Without exact version numbers for all of the packages here, this is not going to be easy to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `breqn` package has undergone a thorough revision from the version in TeX Live 2009 to the one in TeX Live 2010 (which is identical to the version in TeX Live 2011).

The error is triggered by the fact that `flexisym.sty` changes the category code of `^` too early, so that a syntax such as `` \catcode`\^^@ `` which is needed by `listings` is not legal any more: for it to work the `^` must have category code 7 and not 12.

The newer versions of the packages `breqn` and `flexisym` delay the category code change at begin document, so packages can still use the `^^` notation. This was clearly a misfeature in `breqn` and `flexisym`, but explains why loading `breqn` last might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The newer version of `breqn` leaves `_` of catcode letter :(. That's because it's only half-translated to the expl3 syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The issue needs to be traced carefully (as I don't have the old distribution is difficult to trace exactly).

However, the error can possibly as a first step be traced back to the `listings` package based on the error message you have provided.

The macro `\lst@InputCatcodes` is called if a `listings.cfg` file exists. Can you check the distributions to see if there are differences?

Comment: Thanks Yiannis, I will check to see if the `listings` package has changed in the two distributions.